# Is it possible to access global functions from other module?

Tags: python

I'm extending an existing module that has defined a function that I want to use

```
import os
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


git_root_cache = {}

def open_url(url):
    sublime.active_window().run_command('open_url', {"url": url})
```

From the same plugin I have managed to import and run functions running inside classes:

```
class PanagoraBuildCommand(GitWindowCommand, sublime_plugin.TextCommand, sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        #Get the git-folder-name
        workingDir = self.get_working_dir()
```

How can I run the functions from the dependent module inside my class. I cannot change the existing module.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but from the description I don't undestand anything. What function do you want to call?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call the open_url() method which is a part of git module from the PanagoraBuildCommand class, then you have to:

```
from git import open_url
```

Then, in your PanagoraBuildCommand class, you can simply call:

```
open_url(<<value for url parameter>>)
```